# Bioinformatics in Python: Is there a less lengthy approach to my code? Has a lot of "if" and "for" statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, bioinformatics

```
def prot_from_rf(aa_seq):
    prot1 = []
    global proteins
    for aa in aa_seq:
        if aa == "_":
            if prot1:
                for p in prot1:
                    proteins.append(p)
                prot1 = []
        else:
            if aa == "M":
                prot1.append("")
            for i in range(len(prot1)):
                prot1[i] += aa
    return proteins

Input:
MNQT_CLI_VVQLSPHLYRWISTCVNASSRRRPKRKIPCTQSPRELYTD

Output:
MNQT
```

The goal of this code is to scan an amino acid sequence and append the proteins made between start and end codons to a list(proteins). Prot1 is a temporary list where the unprocessed amino acid sequence goes into to start. Was wondering if there is a less lengthy approach to accomplish the same thing.

For people not familiar with biology, I am taking a long string of letters where if there is an "M" it starts to accumulate the characters until it reaches a "_", then it stops and adds this new string to a list(global proteins) not including the "_" character.

Comment: Is `aa_seq` a list of characters or a string?

Comment: The fact that you are using mutable global state is the biggest issue here.  In any case, you need to provide a better problem specification, ideally with example inputs and outputs. Since python is dynamically typed, you have to give people this for a full understanding of the function.

Comment: It is a string. @trincot

Comment: The description in the last paragraph does not seem to explain why `prot1` can have more than one string. It seems that there can be multiple "M" before a "\_" is encountered, and so each "M" starts a new string, whereby the newer string is always a suffix of the previous string(s) in `prot1`. Is that correct?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks I changed that over.

Comment: @trincot I believe the way I have it is at the end of the for statement I have it reassigned to an empty list.

Comment: Is it possible to get multiple "M" before a "\_"? Like "MxxMxx\_"? What should happen?

Comment: @trincot yes. If there are 2 "M"s before a "_" it should output 2 results.

Comment: Sorry to insist. For "MxxMyy_", would the 2 results be "MxxMyy" and "Myy"?

Comment: This would be more on-topic for https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Please see [their guidelines for a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @EthanHetrick, did you get my last question?

Comment: Yes there should be. For example: MNQTCLMNQ_ should produce both MNQTCLMNQ and MNQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have commented, it is not good practice to use the `global` keyword here. Instead, keep the `proteins` list out of it, and extend it outside of the function.

I would also avoid the concatenation of individual characters, but only collect the offsets of the "M"s, and use those to slice strings once you have reached a terminating "_".

Here is how that would look:

```
def prot_from_rf(aa_seq):
    result = []
    starts = []
    for i, ch in enumerate(aa_seq):
        if ch == "_":
            result.extend([aa_seq[m:i] for m in starts])
            starts = []
        elif ch == "M":
            starts.append(i)
    return result
```

Call as:

```
proteins = []
# ...
proteins.extend(prot_from_rf("NMNQT_CLI_VVMQLSMPHLYR_WISTCVNAMSS"))

print(proteins)
```

### Previous answer

Previously it remained unclear to me whether your code was actually dealing correctly with the situation where there are multiple "M" characters before a "_" occurs.

If the intended behavior would have been that a second "M" actually ends a sequence (if one was ongoing) and immediately starts the next, then you can use a regular expression.

```py
import re

def prot_from_rf(aa_seq):
    return re.findall(r"M[^M_]*", aa_seq)

# Example use:
proteins = []
# ...
proteins.extend(prot_from_rf("MNQT_CLI_VVQLSPHLYRWISTCVNASSRRRPKRKIPCTQSPRELYTD"))

print(proteins)
```

Comment: "M" only starts a sequence and it never ends one. Only "_" ends the sequence. A sequence must have an "M" to start and a "_" to end or else it should not be added to the proteins list.

Comment: Also, I just put my whole program on code review if you have time to check it out! @trincot

Comment: OK, I see our timezones are quite different ;-) I have updated my answer. As for the question on code review, I see you already have an extensive answer there.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a much cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you can excise:

1) You don't need to declare `proteins` as global. You're only appending and not reassigning, so as long as it's declared in the outer scope of this function, it will be available inside your function.

2) You don't need to check if `prot1` is empty, since the for-loop over an empty array will have no effect.

3) This loop can be shortened:

```
for p in prot1:
    proteins.append(p)
```

is equivalent to:

```
proteins.extend(prot1)
```

This reduces your code to:

```
def prot_from_rf(aa_seq):
    prot1 = []
    for aa in aa_seq:
        if aa == "_":
            proteins.extend(prot1)
            prot1 = []
        else:
            if aa == "M":
                prot1.append("")
            for i in range(len(prot1)):
                prot1[i] += aa
    return proteins
```